# Sitecore MongoDB Compatibility Version for Sitecore 8.2 update2

Tags: upgrade, mongodb

As per the Sitecore recommendation from the below link Mongo 4.0.5 is recommended for Sitecore 8.2 without mentioning any update version.

[MongoDB compatibility table link](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0633863#notes)

We plan to upgrade Mongo from 3.6 to 4.0.5 for Sitecore 8.2 Update-2 rev. 161221.

Can someone please help whether we can go for mongo 4.0.5 version for 8.2 update 2 without any issues and if yes, Do we need to upgrade mongo provider dll's as part of 4.0.5?. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Since MongoDB 4.0.5 is officially supported for Sitecore 8.2.2, you should not encounter any issues during upgrade. Regarding MongoDB driver, you can find driver version compatibility version [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/csharp/#mongodb-compatibility). According to that table, the minimum driver version that supports both 3.6 and 4.0.5 is 2.7. However, MongoDB driver included in Sitecore rev. 161221 installation is 1.10, so most likely you will need to upgrade the dll.

[image: MongoDB driver]

Since Sitecore has implemented their own MongoDB provider, there is a good chance that you will not need to update MongoDB driver. If I were you, I would:

- Upgrade MongoDB to 4.0.5, but do not upgrade MongoDB.Driver.dll.
- Verify that Sitecore Analytics and session provider still works
- In case of any issues, upgrade the dll and contact Sitecore support since it would indicate that their documentation is not accurate.